# Passing Parameters via URI in Android

Tags: android

Is it possible (or recommended) to pass parameters to content providers via URIs in Android, similar to how web addresses use them?  That is to say, can I use name/value pairs in content:// URIs?

For example, I have a search provider that can search based on names.  I pass it a URI like this:

content://com.example.app/name/john

That would return anyone with "john" in their names, including John, Johnathon, Johnson, etc.

I want to have the option (but not requirement) to search by exact names and not find partial matches.  I was thinking of doing something like this:

content://com.example.app/name/john?exact=true

That would tell the search provider to only return names that exactly match "John."  But I haven't seen any other examples of parameters used like this within Android.  Is there a better way?  What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

if you want to pass query parameters you can use the appendQueryParameter() method when constructing your URI

```
LoaderFactory.createCursorLoader(this,
                MyProvider.MY_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(
                        MyProvider.MY_PARAM_NAME,
                        myParamValue).build(), projection, null,
                null, null);
```

And then access the param value using the getQueryParameter()

```
String paramValue = uri.getQueryParameter(MyProvider.MY_PARAM_NAME);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I have seen, any parameters get stripped from content provider urls (although I don't know why), I worked around this by adding parameters using a "/" and a certain prefix and parse them out manually, something like this:

```
content://com.example.app/name/john/paramexact/true
```

Comment: These are segments, parameters are a bit different - for example "content://com.example.app/table/seg1/123456?param=value"